# Есть ли для декодировки mp3 открытые библиотеки?

Tags: c++, mp3, поиск-библиотек

Знаю, что есть библиотеки ([lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/), [mpg123](http://www.mpg123.de/api/group__mpg123__examples.shtml)), которые позволяют обрабатывать mp3 и работать с данными самого звука, но они под лицензией LGPL, я так понимаю, должна быть возможность замены на другие версии таких либ в производном приложении.

Есть ли библиотеки, желательно бесплатные, для декодировки mp3 в pcm формат, которые можно использовать без обязательной линковки такой либы, например, для коммерческих целей?

Comment: Извините, а LGPL чем не нравится?

Comment: LGPL требует возможность подмены либы в любой момент. 
А если необходимо разместить приложение на google play там будет выкачиваться 1 файл(.apk) то есть конечный пользователь будет лишен возможности подменить либу, например, на новую версию.

или я не прав?

Comment: Сложный вопрос. А не могли бы Вы процитировать LGPL на предмет подмены либы в любой момент?

Comment: Определения из википедии: "Essentially, if it is a "work that uses the library", then it must be possible for the software to be linked with a newer version of the LGPL-covered program. The most commonly used method for doing so is to use "a suitable shared library mechanism for linking". Alternatively, a statically linked library is allowed if either source code or linkable object files are provided."

Comment: [Вот тут](http://forum.vingrad.ru/topic-326227.html) нашел (IMHO) отличный ответ на похожий вопрос про LGPL.

Суть в том, что **можно** статически линковать **свое закрытое** приложение с LGPL, но **Вы обязаны** по первому требованию его **пользователя** предоставить ему возможность пользоваться **новой версией** библиотеки под LGPL.

Поэтому, во избежании эксцессов все предпочитают не связываться со статикой. 

--

А уж как юзер (в случае динамической сборки) будет брать новую .so (или .dll) это его проблемы

(это уже моя интерпретация).

Comment: @maxmail, а что Вам мешает просто взять сорсы и выдрать из них нужные именно для вашей программы куски кода (и, может быть, тоже сделать свой код свободным)?

Не считаете же Вы всерьез, что можно реально заработать на коде (пряча его от остальных программеров)?

Comment: А если случиться так: обновиться либа с LGPL, которую я использую в приложении, но там есть некая ошибка, и я, например, ее нашел. Я ведь могу предоставить новую версию этой либы, но я не могу гарантировать, насколько корректно будет работать приложение после обновления. Такое ведь может случиться?

Comment: @maxmail, ну, я не знаю деталей Вашего бизнеса (кому и на каких условиях Вы поставляете продукт).

В конце-концов просто напишите в своем лицензионном (или что у Вас там?) соглашении, что покупатель берет все риски на себя.

Не нравится -- пусть не берет.